# Postgres: How to increment the index (pointer) to access other rows

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to understand how to increment the reference to some value.

In C I would simply increment the pointer to retrieve a value in the next array location.

How does this mechanism work in Postgres? is it possible?

For an example, I have created a table with some data in:

```
create table mathtest (
x int, y int, val int)

insert into mathtest (x,y,val)
values (1,1,10),(2,2,20),(3,3,30),(4,4,40),(5,5,50),(6,6,60),(7,7,70),(8,8,80),(9,9,90),(10,10,100),(11,11,110)
```

What I want to do is add the val value from the current row and then the val value when the x value in the row equals the current x value plus 2, and then plus 4. I realise that I can't assume the next row that is retrieved will be in a set order so I can't use 'lead'

If it was C I would simply increment the pointer.

The data output needs to be when the modulo of x and y = 0 for certain divisors. (this bit works)

```
select
    x base,
    (x+2) plus1x,
    (x+4) plus2x,
    y,
    val
from mathtest
where  x%2 =0 and y%3 = 0
```

This outputs the following:

```
       base     plus1x      plus2x     y    val
1       6         8           10       6     60
```

The output I would like is:

60 + 80 +100 = 240

I can't conceptualise how to do it. My mind seems to be stuck in procedural C mode!

Whatever I type and try is an error.

Can any body help me to get over this hurdle?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what exactly the output is you want. Can you please add a sample similar to the one you have for the current one you have. You can use the `lead()` function to access values of following rows. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name I'm sorry for the in-exactitude. I want to place the output into another table called output. output will contain x int, y int, val int. When I find an x and y value in the mathtest table where the x and y meets the modulo criteria I then want to store the current x and y in the output x and y. The output table val entry is calculated by taking the current val from the mathtable, then adding the val from mathtable 2 rows in front (use the val value where that rows x = current x +2) and 4 rows in front (y value stays the same). I am dealing with cartesian corodinates.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-window.html).

You need an explicit ordering, otherwise it makes no sense to speak of the "previous row".

As a simple example, to get the difference to the previous value, you can query like

```
SELECT val -
       lag(val) OVER (ORDER BY x)
FROM mathtest;
```